# In Linked List creation why do we take the pointer used for traversing having the same data type as that of the linked list nodes?

Tags: pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
    } *head;

    void insert(){
    **struct node *traverse**; 
    struct node *newnode=new node();
    cout<<"enter the value\n";
    cin>>val;
    newnode->data=val;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    traverse = head;
    if(head==NULL)
    head=newnode;

    else {
             while(traverse->next!=NULL)
                 traverse=traverse->next;


        traverse->next=newnode;
        traverse=traverse->next;

 }


}
    }
```

Basically, I want to know why the traverse pointer is of struct node data type only?
Why cant we use an integer or any other data type pointer instead?

Comment: It points to a node, so it is a pointer to node. Why should it be an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was another type of pointer you can't do

> traverse=traverse->next;

You make traverse point to the next item in list, which in turn should have a struct member "next", and so on.

Using pointers this way is the easiest way to use linked lists. Using ints or any other ID's would mean that the linked list will be implemented via some kind of indexed array, and therefore needs more logic to handle the index and cope with expanding or decreasing array size. The fun part of linked-lists is that you can remove parts of the link or add one somewhere in the middle, without having to re-arrange the *whole* list.